# How to extract cardinality of key value pairs in a given column

Tags: sql, database, presto

I have a table that contains two columns metric and dimensionName=dimensionValue key value pairs such that the data is stored as:

| metric | dimensions |
| --- | --- |
| A | {x=1, y=2, z=3, p=4, q=5} |
| A | {x=1, y=2, z=3, p=4, q=5} |
| A | {x=2, y=2, z=3, p=4, q=5} |
| A | {x=2, y=3, z=3, p=4, q=5} |
| A | {x=3, y=4, z=3, p=4, q=5} |

I want to get all the unique combinations involving dimensions x and y in this table ie I want to treat x=1,y=2 as the same combination in row 1 and 2 so ultimately the cardinality of key value pairs involving x and y in this table will be 4 since there will be 4 unique combinations of {x,y} values (x=1,y=2), (x=2,y=2), (x=2,y=3) and (x=3,y=4).

Follow up: I also would like to get unique combinations where I exclude dimensions as well so exclude x and y such that I need unique combinations of {z,p,q}

So far I tried using unnest but that is giving me two columns dimensionName and dimensionValue but I was not sure how to get the unique combo with x and y values being in different rows

```
SELECT 
  dimension_name, dimension_value 
FROM 
  "metrics" 
CROSS JOIN 
  UNNEST(dimensions) AS dimension_map(dimension_name, dimension_value) 
WHERE metric='A' AND dimension_name IN ('x', 'y');
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @arjunj, I think I have an answer for your question, please have a try.  In short, you can use Presto subscript and distinct operators  to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to original question**:

In Presto, you can get the result you want in the following steps:

1. Use map key and [Presto subscript operator](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html) to fetch the (x,y) dimension values and store them in 2 columns (dim_x,dim_y)
2. Filter any row which may not have map value by map key (x or y)
3. Use a [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) operator to distinct (dim_x, dim_y) pair in the input data.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    dimensions['x'] as dim_x,
    dimensions['y'] as dim_y 
FROM 
    "metrics"
WHERE
    metric = 'A'
AND
    dimensions['x'] IS NOT NULL
AND
    dimensions['y'] IS NOT NULL
```

| dim_x | dim_y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

**Answer to the follow-up**:

To further extend the solution to n dimensions instead of 2 dimensions, we can use Presto [map_filter()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_filter) function to get desired spec map first and then group by submaps.

Here is the query:

```
WITH spec_metrics AS (
SELECT
    metric,
    map_filter(dimensions,(k, v) -> k in ('x','y')) as spec_dimensions
FROM 
    "metrics"
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT spec_dimensions
FROM
    spec_metrics
WHERE
    metric = 'A'
AND
    CARDINALITY(spec_dimensions) = 2
```

If we want to further get the count instead of distinct dimension combination, we can change the query to use count(distinct) operator.

Here is the query:

```
WITH spec_metrics AS (
SELECT
    metric,
    map_filter(dimensions,(k, v) -> k in ('x','y')) as spec_dimensions
FROM 
    "metrics"
)
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT spec_dimensions) as spec_combination_cnt
FROM
    spec_metrics
WHERE
    metric = 'A'
AND
    CARDINALITY(spec_dimensions) = 2
```

To further extend the solution to n dimensions and do an exclusion of (x,y) instead of includsion of (x,y) , we can still use Presto [map_filter()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_filter) function and NOT operator to get desired spec map first and then group by submaps.

Here is the query:

```
WITH spec_metrics AS (
SELECT
    metric,
    map_filter(dimensions,(k, v) -> k NOT in ('x','y')) as spec_dimensions,
    MAX(CARDINALITY(dimensions)) OVER (PARTITION BY metric) as total_dimension_cnt
FROM 
    "metrics"
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT spec_dimensions
FROM
    spec_metrics
WHERE
    metric = 'A'
AND
    CARDINALITY(spec_dimensions) = total_dimension_cnt - 2
```

Comment: Thanks this good. I have a couple questions. If lets say i want to include more dimensions. My query might have n dimensions then we will have n 'AND's in the query. Wondering if there is a optimal way in that case? Also how to get the cardinality of this result table ie get count of 4. I am new to PrestoSQL so did not find any examples for that.

Comment: HI @arjunj. Yes, to extend it to n required dimensions, we can use presto_filter() function to filter only requird dimensions and then have distinct operator on the remaining dimensions I have updated the answer to also include this part. please have another try.

Comment: for " how to get the cardinality of this result table ie get count of 4", instead of distinct, you can use count(distinct) operator to get the count of 4.

Comment: Cool thanks for updating and adding the query. What is the benefit of adding the cardinality(spec_dimensions) = 2 ?

Comment: Hi @arjunj, cardinality(spec_dimensions) = 2 will filter out the result which only have dimensions x or dimensions y or none of the dimensions.

Comment: I see, since we already filtered dimensions x and y in the first query above.  I wonder if we need that, I verified that result is 4 even without that cardinality(spec_dimensions) condition.

Comment: Hi @arjunj. that's because your current input are always in the format of {x, y, z}, what if your input is {x,z} or {y,z} or {z} or simply null. that's where cardinality(spec_dimensions) = 2 will safeguard the result.

Comment: Ah makes sense! So follow up is if I need to do not in instead of in ie lets say i do not care about x and y but only care about z and any other n dimensions in that. Problem is my input will either be in or not in along with a list of dimensions so I cannot do = 2 for the second case because i wont know z and n other dimensions. Is there a way to do that? Really appreciate the help here. This is my last use-case for this qn.

Comment: Hi @arjunj, in this case, you can first change to 'NOT in' in the map_filter condition. they will return any other dimension except (x, y), if you are looking for results with at least one other dimension, then use 'cardinality(spec_dimensions) > 0', if you are looking for results with all others dimensions (n-2), then use 'cardinality(spec_dimensions) = n - 2'. I have update the answer for this part.

Comment: But we wont know n beforehand. Is there a way to compute n and use that in the second query. Also we will never have null in that column so it will always have some dimensions but it can be any number of dimensions for each row. to make example simpler i used x,y,z in all rows but it can be varying length so makes it trickier.

Comment: Hi @arjunj, to clarify, are you saying you are expecting n is the same across all rows, we should get the max value? and you can expecting use "'cardinality(spec_dimensions) = n - 2' at the end?

Comment: Yeah n can be of varying length, I updated the table in qn to help visualize the input data set. So I need all unique combinations of the case where either we care about 2 dimensions (IN case) or we care about n-2 dimensions (NOT IN case)

Comment: Hi @arjunj, what is your expected results in this case?{z=3, p=4},  {z=3, p=4, q=5}, {z=3, p=4}, {z=3, p=4, q=5}???

Comment: Sorry. Actually i gave it some thought and realized that we will have n dimensions fixed per row. So let's just go with that and that simplifies this problem. Updated table again. So how do I get n = 5 on the fly such that I can do "cardinality(spec_dimensions) = n -2 ie cardinality(spec_dimensions) = 3"?

Comment: So in above table the unique combincations for not in (x,y) case will be 1 because there is only one unique combination of (z=3,p=4,q=5)

Comment: Got it, I have updated the last query in the answer to use max() and window function to get n on the fly. It should work for your last request. Let me know if you have any further question.